# float value from [NSString floatValue] show different result when print out

Tags: ios, objective-c, floating-point

Please look at the code below and the result in console.

```
NSString *strRatio = @"0.03" ;
float f = [strRatio floatValue] ;
NSLog(@"%f, %@", f, f == 0.03 ? @"equal" : @"not equal") ;
```

result:

`0.030000, not equal`

Also I have a screenshot when I add a breakpoint at `NSLog(@"%f, %@", f, f == 0.03 ? @"equal" : @"not equal") ;` , it gives me a different value of `f` showing 0.0299999993...

Can anyone explain it ?

1. Why is the result of `f == 0.03` is false ?
2. Why the value of f printed is 0.030000 but it shows 0.0299999993 when debug.

[image]

Edit :

I expect that the value of f is 0.03 after converting from @"0.03", how can I achieve it ?

It seems that float can't represent 0.03. Even if I assign 0.03 to float value forcibly, I will get 0.029999993 as the result.

Comment: `float` uses a binary representation and *cannot* represent 0.03. The first part of your question is a duplicate of [strange output in comparison of float with float literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839422/strange-output-in-comparison-of-float-with-float-literal). - See also [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is not `0.03`, it is as shown in the debugger - `0.0299999993`.

It shows as `0.03000` in the log because by default, `%f` shows 5 decimal places so the value `0.0299999993` is being rounded to `0.03000`.

Change the log to use `%.10f` and you will see the real value.

Comment: Actually I expect the float value is 0.03 when converting @"0.03", can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try NSDecimalNumber instead of `[string floatValue];`

```
NSDecimalNumber *number1 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.03"];

NSLog(@"number1: %@", number1); //0.03
```

Comment: `f = [number1 floatValue] ;
    NSLog(@"number1: %.10f", f) ;` still get 0.029999993...

Comment: "Exact float value from a NSString" Not easily. It's entirely possible that the number represented in the NSString has no exact representation as a primitive floating-point type. Refer Question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888509/exact-float-value-from-a-nsstring

Comment: NSLog(@" Number1 : %.2f",f); You will get 0.03. Or use NSDecimalNumber, its a class given like NSNumber which is normally used in such instances.